# Sending multiple variables in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following *ajax* request:

```
var value = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.php",
        data: { $(someform).serialize(), something: test_number },
        cache: false,
        async: true
    }).success(function(data){
        alert("success!");
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("FAILED");
    });
```

But it is *logging* **FAILED** although the url is right. What happens is that the page refreshes the page and the  php query **isn't** done. I guess there are no errors within the url... any idea on why this happens?

Comment: Have you inspected the POST in firebug/chrome?  You need to look at the headers.  The URL won't change with a POST but I suspect your data object is not proper.

Comment: you need to prevent default behaviour of FORM submit. You need to pass correct data to POST request too, then, it should work

Comment: This is a problem in your server side code; error happens on bad php responses. Open up the dev tools and look at the network panel to see what the server is responding with (if it's a php error that causes the script to fail, it'll probably be a 500 server error)

Comment: `{ $(someform).serialize(),` is invalid javascript. Additionally, you may need to prevent the default action to stop the page from reloading.

Answer (score 1):

You are kind of mixing methods to send your POST data.  You can't serialize a query strong and then also append additional data to it using javascript object construct. You will likely need to manually append the last data element to the query string like this:

```
data: $(someform).serialize() + '&something=' + encodeURIComponent(test_number),
```

Of course there could still be a problem on the server-side script which is causing a non-200 HTTP response code (and triggering error handler).  You just need to fix this first, and if you still have a problem, debug the server-side issue.